# Backup from recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, oneplus-one

After trying to install an OTA update, I'm stuck in recovery mode (system won't boot).

I'd like to know if I got any way to backup my datas (Contacts / SMSs / Enventually applications) from recovery like I would do with Titanium Backup and/or equivalent.

I'm using TWRP recovery, just in case.

Comment: I use CWM, and it has an option to restore only selected parts. Check if TWRP has that too. If it does, make a full backup, then re-flash a working ROM, then restore **only** data from the backup, and finally, clear cache and (if applicable) Dalvik cache. I can't guarantee it, but these steps worked for me when I softbricked my old S3.

Comment: @SixthOfFour : I got this option indeed, but does this also include SMS and contacts ?

Comment: I have contacts synced with Gmail, so I don't know about those. And my experience is three years old, so I don't remember about SMS, but I believe those are stored somewhere in /data.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try this anyway, don't got much choice!

Comment: @servabat If you backup everything (*Nandroid*), then it will have **everything** including, SMS, contacts, messages from other apps, *all* applications and even modifications done to the system partition (`/system` is backed up as well as `/data`)

Comment: @GiantTree : Yes but how can I use this kind of datas ? Is there a way to 'unpack' Nandroids ? (because I don't really wish to restore system as this one is bricked !)

Comment: @GiantTree If you restore only /data, the /system partition is left untouched by the restore operation. At least with CWM.

Comment: @SixthOfFour it's the same with TWRP. You can choose what to backup and what to restore.

Comment: @servabat all of the files (the `.win` ones) are images of the corresponding partitions. They usually have their file system format attached to the name (eg. `.ext4.win` for ext4 partitions). In Linux you can mount them as normal drives, in Windows it's somewhat more difficult, because there is no official support for those file systems.

Comment: @GiantTree : I'm using Linux, I'll try `mount` then. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I finally did a nandroid then used Titanium ! It has a function to extract from nandroids.